# How do I detect if a usb input device is plugged in?

Tags: raspbian, usb, linux

I am using [xboxdrv](https://github.com/Grumbel/xboxdrv) for my MAME controls, however I also want to use my arcade controls via the GPIO also. To do this,  on boot up if a xbox controller is detected, I want to load the xboxdrv program, but if it is not, I want to load my program that interfaces my Arcade controls to the GPIO.

How do I detect if the xbox controler is plugged in? I can see the controller in `/var/log/messages`

```
Mar 29 11:17:17 raspberrypi kernel: [    6.134223] input: Microsoft X-Box 360 pad as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input0
```

I would be doing this with a bash script like so:

```
#! /bin/bash
STR=$(lsusb | grep "Xbox360 Controller")

if [[ $STR == *Xbox360* ]]; then
 echo "x-box driver found"
else
  echo "load custom arcade controls"
fi
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try looking into `udev`. With udev you can run command on events, like `add` and `remove`, of a usb device.

Comment: Plugging in the Xbox controller should result in the creation of a `/dev/input/eventX` device. You can use udev to have be static, then just check for the existence of the device file.

Comment: Have any examples?

Comment: since your comments on creating a udev rule are a bit off topic for my original question, I asked that question in the unix/linux SE http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/add-udev-rule-alias-for-input-device

Answer (score 1):

Plug and play functionality in Linux is handled via `udev` rules, which look like this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{name}=="Xbox*", SUBSYSTEM=="input", RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

Essentially, instead of checking for the device presence, you get your script executed the moment the device is plugged in ("added").

There are already several Github projects ([1](https://github.com/parasven/Xboxdrv-controller-scripts), [2](https://gist.github.com/encounter/458c518c6e4a7b896de7)) which you can study to understand how such rules and scripts are written.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

The device is a GPSdongle which I gave the device name 'ttyUSBGMOUSE' using the 'USB port names rules' procedure

import os
import subprocess
rv4 = subprocess.call("sudo ls /dev | grep 'ttyUSBGMOUSE'", shell=True)
print(rv4)

0 if it is attached, 1 if not